# Intuitive understanding of Markov Chains

Tags: machine-learning, markov-process

I am looking for an intuitive understanding of Markov chains. As far as I understood, barring some edge cases, the probability of arriving at state `j` when starting from state `i` converges to a specific value *after n timesteps, where n tends to infinity*.  What do these `n` timesteps mean? Does it mean after `n` timesteps, someone can confidently say what the probability of arriving at state `j` when starting from state `i` is without performing any computation? Why couldn't they just say that from `n=0`?

Major edit - I realized that I did not clarify n to be infinite. I am basically confused with the meaning of “steady state ” probability. Does it mean that your probability of arriving at some state is fixed given that you start now and traverse the chain for n time steps, where n is huge? For simplicity we can assume that it’s a single recurrent system that doesn’t depend on initial state.

Comment: "After $n$ timesteps" is virtually meaningless in the context of convergence, which concerns *arbitrarily large* index values.  A quick review of limits and convergence might be the best way for you to address this.

Comment: My apologies for this mistake. Please let me know if something is still unclear. I am a little bit of a newbie with this topic.

Comment: I tried to edit the reponse to address your edit about the steady state probability

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/133214/14893

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, the text you are reading means that you are in state $i$ at some time $t$, and look at the probability that you are in state $j$ after $n$ *additional* time steps, that is at time $t+n$.

It is a very characteristic property of Markov chains, that the time $t$ where you start does *not* matter. This is actually called "Markov property" and means that the past history, before time $t$, has no influence on the future.

The probability to be in state $j$ after $n$ time steps, when you started in $i$, can be denoted as $P^n(i, j)$. The convergence result that you mentioned means that $P^n(i,j)$ converges to a constant which we could call $P^\infty(i,j)$, as $n$ goes to infinity.

In response to edit:
For any $n$, the probability to get from $i$ to $j$ after $n$ steps is always fixed, but if the chain is "nice enough" to have exactly one stationary steady state, these probabilities converge to a number and that no longer depends on $i$. Then $P^\infty(i,j) = \pi(j)$, where $\pi(j)$ is the probability of being in state $j$ in steady state.

 By "a chain is nice enough" I meant that it is irreducible and recurrent.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/297334/14893